# Change background image size with media query

Tags: css

```css
.logo {
    background-image: url(https://ofbuckleyandbeatles.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/testpattern.gif);
    background-size: 100%;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
.logo {
    background-image: url(https://ofbuckleyandbeatles.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/testpattern.gif);
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
    }
```

```html
<div class="logo"> </div>
```

I can't work out why this doesn't work - any ideas why the image doesn't render?

HTML:

```
<div class="logo"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
background-image: url(../img/logo_white.png);
background-size: 100%;}

@media(max-width:767px) {
.logo {
background-image: url(../img/logo_white.png);
background-size: 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: can you add a reproduction of the issue (jsfiddle/code snippet) and/or provide more details of "why it doesn't work"?

Comment: @panther @ slime has the right answer below :)

Comment: @somethinghere: no, it works without declaring `device - screen/all/etc.`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px)
```

Comment: Even better (since this is a catchall and very generic question): `@media all`, but yes, good catch.

Comment: It should have worked, but if not...then I suspect is has something to do with the container that the logo is in. Also, maybe try `50% 50%`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you syntax was wrong. Secondly, at least in the code you provided, your div was zero size. See how it works:

```css
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 99%;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-image: url('http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mountains.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .logo {
    background-size: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

But is it that you want for responsive design? Probably you misunderstood the meaning of `background-size: 50%;` property?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm mate, heres a simple one: give your wrapper some height.

```css
.logo {
    background-image: url(https://ofbuckleyandbeatles.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/testpattern.gif);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;   
    height: 100px;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    .logo {
        background-image: url(https://ofbuckleyandbeatles.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/testpattern.gif);
      background-size: 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"> </div>
```

Comment: Doh!  Didn't declare a width for the DIV.

Thank you all.